# AngularJS asp.net MVC on IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, iis

I have an asp.net project that uses angular.js.
An example of the project can be found here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par

When i attempt to run the project on my IIS Sever, the following function, which should return a string does not.

```
      $http.post('Home/GetListOfVendors')
.success(function (response) { 
    console.log(response);
        })
.error(function (response) { 
    console.log("error");
});
```

Instead, it returns the actual html file, along with all tags, etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code for 'GetListOfVendors'?

Comment: in 'HomeController.cs'

Comment: Could you please post all of your code?  Do you have script tags for your module and controller on your view?  There could be so many reasons, but without seeing more of your code, it is difficult to help.

Comment: i solved the issue by putting the solution file in the root folder of the project. Not sure why this worked though